# GetNeighborhood function for 3D cells structure in MATLAB

Tags: beginner, matrix, matlab

I am attempting to implement a `GetNeighborhood` function in order to get a specific region from `inputCells` by `sizeInput` and `centralLocation` parameters in 3D cells structure.

**The experimental implementation**

The experimental implementation of `GetNeighborhood` function is as below.

```
function [output] = GetNeighborhood(inputCells, sizeInput, centralLocation)
    %   Get neighborhood of fixed size and centered at centralLocation
    output = cell( sizeInput ,sizeInput ,sizeInput );
    X = centralLocation(1);
    Y = centralLocation(2);
    Z = centralLocation(3);
    for x = -sizeInput:sizeInput
        for y = -sizeInput:sizeInput
            for z = -sizeInput:sizeInput
                if X + x < 1
                    xLocation = 1;
                elseif X + x > size(inputCells, 1)
                    xLocation = size(inputCells, 1);
                else
                    xLocation = X + x;
                end
                
                if Y + y < 1
                    yLocation = 1;
                elseif Y + y > size(inputCells, 2)
                    yLocation = size(inputCells, 2);
                else
                    yLocation = Y + y;
                end
                
                if Z + z < 1
                    zLocation = 1;
                elseif Z + z > size(inputCells, 3)
                    zLocation = size(inputCells, 3);
                else
                    zLocation = Z + z;
                end
                
                output{sizeInput + x + 1, sizeInput + y + 1, sizeInput + z + 1} = ...
                    inputCells{xLocation, yLocation, zLocation};
            end
        end
    end
end
```

**Test cases**

For testing purpose, a simple test script is created as below.

```
clear all;
clc;
close all;
set(groot,'defaultFigureVisible','on');

%% Create test cells

testCellsSize = 10;

test = cell(testCellsSize, testCellsSize, testCellsSize);
for x = 1:size(test, 1)
    for y = 1:size(test, 2)
        for z = 1:size(test, 3)
            test{x, y, z} = [x * 100 + y * 10 + z];
        end
    end
end

%% Specify test parameters

NeighborhoodDist = 1;
centralLocation = [5 2 2];

%% Perform test

result = GetNeighborhood(test, NeighborhoodDist, centralLocation);
result
```

The output of the above testing code:

```
  3×3×3 cell array

result(:,:,1) = 

    {[411]}    {[421]}    {[431]}
    {[511]}    {[521]}    {[531]}
    {[611]}    {[621]}    {[631]}


result(:,:,2) = 

    {[412]}    {[422]}    {[432]}
    {[512]}    {[522]}    {[532]}
    {[612]}    {[622]}    {[632]}


result(:,:,3) = 

    {[413]}    {[423]}    {[433]}
    {[513]}    {[523]}    {[533]}
    {[613]}    {[623]}    {[633]}
```

If there is any possible improvement about potential drawback or unnecessary overhead, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the biggest gain in efficiency you can get is to  not use a cell array. Each element of a cell array is an array. Each array has a header data structure that takes up 104 bytes (if I remember that number correctly). Storing only one number in an array means that there is a memory overhead of 104/(104+8)=92%. Access is also slower because of the double indirection. To store individual numbers you should always use a numeric array.

This code:

```
if X + x < 1
   xLocation = 1;
elseif X + x > size(inputCells, 1)
   xLocation = size(inputCells, 1);
else
   xLocation = X + x;
end
```

has quite some redundancy. Every time you write the same expression twice, you should think about storing the result of the expression. Even if the computation is trivial and likely not to slow down your code, duplicated code still leads to maintenance issues. You could do instead:

```
xLocation = X + x;
maxLocation = size(inputCells, 1);
if xLocation < 1
   xLocation = 1;
elseif xLocation > maxLocation
   xLocation = maxLocation
end
```

This can be further simplified using `max` and `min`:

```
xLocation = X + x;
xLocation = max(xLocation, 1);
xLocation = min(xLocation, size(inputCells, 1));
```

You could maybe even simplify this to a single line of code, though that doesn’t improve readability:

```
xLocation = min(max(X + x, 1), size(inputCells, 1));
```

Furthermore, this code is repeated three times, so you should make it into a function you can call three times.

Once your input and output are numeric arrays, you can likely vectorize the operation, removing the loops and further simplifying the code.

`clear all` is not recommended. `clear` by itself clears the workspace, deleting all defined variables. Adding the `all` argument causes it to additionally remove from memory all parsed and pre-compiled functions, meaning that the next time you call those functions they’ll take longer to run. `clear all` is hardly ever needed, and should not be a part of your normal workflow.